# Trying a basic audio Level teller but it gives wrong answer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        float A;
    printf("Pls write the decibel\n");
    scanf("%f",&A);
            if (49<A,60>A)
            {printf("quiet\n");}
                else if (70>A,59<A)
                    {printf("Anoying\n");}
                    else if (80>A,69<A)
                    {printf("to Anoying\n");}
                        else if (90>A,79<A)
                       {printf("Very Anoying\n");}
                            else if (101>A,89<A)
                          {printf("Extreamly Anoying\n");}
                                else if (A>100)
                                   {printf("You Are Dead\n");}       
                                   else if (50>A);

                                       {printf("To Low\n");}
    return 0;
}
```

Lets say I am writing over 100 it says too low and anoying at the same time and none of them true, what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: `(49<A,60>A)` --> `(A>49 && A<60)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is a semicolon after `else if (50>A);` which ends that
  statement so that the next `printf` gets executed anyway.
- You also should use logical AND operator (`&&`) instead of the comma operator
  in your conditionals.

The modified program will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float A;
    printf("Pls write the decibel\n");
    scanf("%f",&A);
    if (49<A && 60>A)
        {printf("Quiet\n");}
    else if (70>A && 59<A)
        {printf("Annoying\n");}
    else if (80>A && 69<A)
        {printf("Too Annoying\n");}
    else if (90>A && 79<A)
        {printf("Very Annoying\n");}
    else if (101>A && 89<A)
        {printf("Extremely Annoying\n");}
    else if (A>100)
        {printf("You Are Dead\n");}       
    else if (50>A)
        {printf("Too Low\n");}
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Pls write the decibel                                                                                                          
101                                                                                                                            
You Are Dead
```

Comment: Thank You So Much i should be more carefull about (;) thanks.